# Is it normal for a PWM fan with a potentiometer to compensate by pulling additional current or is there additional circuitry?

Tags: potentiometer, fan

I've modded a laptop fan with a potentiometer on the positive wire to adjust its speed manually. I've done this before without problem on other laptops but this one will just continually up the voltage or something to compensate.

What happens is I'll adjust the fan and it will slow down. Then after a moment it will spin back up. If I do this a couple times and then turn the pot down then the fan will spin much faster than it normally ever would on its own at 5v. I can only assume that this is a result of the fan being given additional voltage by the system.

I'm considering tapping a constant 5v from elsewhere which I think will work.

The third wire is only supposed to be a tachometer so I'm surprised that the system would increase the voltage past 5v. Maybe there is a closed loop sensor?

Has anyone encountered anything like this before or can explain why the laptop keeps compensating with more power?

**UPDATE**

Added photos of how I have the potentiometer wired up.

I'm going to take the laptop apart and double-check voltages on everything. I have to disassemble everything as the fan is on the very bottom beneath the motherboard.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you running a reostat setup for a PWM fan with feedback? Please draw a schematic!

Comment: This really isn't going to work without a schematic - please can you edit your question and add one. The schematic editor here is a breeze to use, don't just post a giant photo of a hand sketch.

Comment: Did you actually measure the 5V increasing?

Comment: Is this a three-wire or four-wire fan?  I doubt the supply is rising past 5V as that would be a bizarre and somewhat irresponsible way of controlling fan speed.  My guess is that you are tripping the locked-rotor sensor and the auto-restart circuit is applying a bit of extra torque to clear it.

Comment: No schematic but instead giant photos creating a scrollfest and hard to read question, so downvoting.

Comment: Do these quarter-watt pots lose resistance when they heat close to melting point?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fan you are using, which is the common PWM fan. Older PWM fans did not have enhancement mode MOSFETs as its integrated PWM driver, so someone could hook up a simple linear control and the speed would vary like that. Technically, the PWM lead is a pulse-off with a low, at a rate above 20 kHz typically to control the fan.

Grounding the PWM lead should turn off the fan (if it doesn't, your fan has a malfunction). Some 5V fans have a pull up resistor tied to its tach or rpm output lead, and in those cases, connecting the tach output (rpm out) lead to the PWM will cause the fan to go into 50% duty cycle, or half speed.

On 12 and 24V PWM fans, you have keep in mind the PWM lead cant go much above 5.5V as it was designed for TTL pulse-off duty cycle management, and have to use a voltage divider network for the RPM lead's "open collector" to power the circuit to be applied to the PWM.